# Issue Converting g++ switches to CMAKE

Tags: cmake, g++, clion, mysql-connector

I am trying to convert the following `g++` into `CMAKE`:

```
$ g++ -Wall -I/usr/include/cppconn -o main main.cpp -L/usr/lib -lmysqlcppconn
```

The above command works perfectly and my MySQL c++ code successfully is built and can be executed.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(untitled)
include_directories(/usr/include/cppconn) # -I/usr/include/cppconn
link_directories(/usr/lib) # -L/usr/lib
target_link_libraries (libmysqlcppconn) # -lmysqlcppconn
add_executable(untitled main.cpp)
```

CMAKE complains about `libmysqlcppconn`. Could someone kindly let me know how I can convert my `g++` into CMAKE?

Comment: What's the error message? You can also run `make VERBOSE=1` to see exact command line being run.

Comment: Normally, `target_link_libraries` accepts at least **two arguments**: the **executable** you want to link, and the **library** you want to link with. That is, correct call would be `target_link_libraries (untitled libmysqlcppconn)`. It should be placed **after** `add_executable()`, which creates the target `untitled`.